# confluent-python kafka producer send callback message.offset() returns 0

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

The Producer.send callback provides a message object. `message.offset()` often returns 0 in what seems to be a bug.

This is using:
confluent-kafka python library version 0.11.0
librdkafka: stable 0.11.0 (bottled), HEAD. Installed via Mac OS Homebrew

The following simple test program:

```
import confluent_kafka
import timeit


def delivery_callback(error, message):
    print("delivery_callback. error={}. message={}".format(error, message))
    print("message.topic={}".format(message.topic()))
    print("message.timestamp={}".format(message.timestamp()))
    print("message.key={}".format(message.key()))
    print("message.value={}".format(message.value()))
    print("message.partition={}".format(message.partition()))
    print("message.offset={}".format(message.offset()))


def produce_string_messages(kafka_producer, topic_name, num_messages):
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()

    for i in range(num_messages):
        kafka_producer.produce(topic_name, value="cf-k test. v{}".format(i), on_delivery=delivery_callback)

    elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
    print("completed producing messages. They are queued for delivery. elapsed={}. elapsed/msg={}".format(elapsed, elapsed / num_messages))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("starting")

    conf = {
        'bootstrap.servers': "kafka-broker-1:9092"
    }

    kafka_producer = confluent_kafka.Producer(conf)

    print("opened KafkaProducer")
    produce_string_messages(kafka_producer, "my-string-topic", 3)

    print("flushing...")
    kafka_producer.flush()

    print("exiting")
```

produces:

```
starting
opened KafkaProducer
completed producing messages. They are queued for delivery. elapsed=0.000994920730591. elapsed/msg=0.00033164024353
flushing...
delivery_callback. error=None. message=<cimpl.Message object at 0x10f986ec0>
message.topic=my-string-topic
message.timestamp=(1, 1508451238822L)
message.key=None
message.value=cf-k test. v0
message.partition=0
message.offset=0
delivery_callback. error=None. message=<cimpl.Message object at 0x10f986ec0>
message.topic=my-string-topic
message.timestamp=(1, 1508451238822L)
message.key=None
message.value=cf-k test. v1
message.partition=0
message.offset=0
delivery_callback. error=None. message=<cimpl.Message object at 0x10f986ec0>
message.topic=my-string-topic
message.timestamp=(1, 1508451238822L)
message.key=None
message.value=cf-k test. v2
message.partition=0
message.offset=24
exiting
```

Notice that `message.offset()` is zero for the first two messages and non-zero for the third. If I run this test program again that sends three messages, the third `message.offset` increments by 3. This looks like just a bug where `message.offset()` often incorrectly returns 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For performance[1] reasons the delivery report only provides a valid offset for the last message in a produced batch. This can be changed to provide proper offsets for all messages in the batch by setting the `produce.offset.report` topic-level configuration property to true, like so:

```
p = confluent_kafka.Producer({'bootstrap.servers': ..., 
                              'default.topic.config': { 'produce.offset.report': True } })
```

We'll change the default to be True in a future release of the Python client.

[1]: It avoids a linear scan of the messages in the batch, but the performance impact is miniscule and irrelevant in Python land, so nothing to worry about.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! As the main author, can you respond to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732214/apt-get-install-librdkafka1-fails-on-debian-9-x-due-to-libssl-dependency